# SSHD won't let me specify HostCertificate using ecdsa and defaults to sending original ed25519 key

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-keygen

Trying to set up SSH authentication with a regular self-signed key host/client certificate setup, and for two days have been completely unable to do so. Followed a couple of different guides, but they're a few years old, and I don't see anything more current to help.

The primary guide I've tried to use: https://goteleport.com/blog/how-to-configure-ssh-certificate-based-authentication/ and the second more cut-down guide: https://ruimarinho.gitbooks.io/yubikey-handbook/content/ssh/authenticating-ssh-host-certificates-client/

Every time I try and set this up, my SSHD server just spits out the original ed25519 key it came installed with, no matter what I change in the config file! <del>I've been attempting to use the newer ecdsa standard instead of ed25519, and I get the same result when trying this with that older type as well.</del> Edit: found out I had it backwards, but my problem still stands.

In the log files it shows on the initial handshake under list_hostkey_types (and further down in the host key algorithms):

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
```

What am I doing wrong? This is a clean install of headless Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (minimized), tried local SSH and Putty from a Windows computer, and it always shows the regular TOFU popup for that default ed25519 key.

### tl;dr

Setting HostCertificate in the sshd_config file doesn't load that certificate as primary to send, and it ends up with the default ed25519 instead of my signed host key.

Comment: ECDSA is the older standard: X9.62 in 1998 and rfc5656 in 2009 implemented by OpenSSH 5.7 in 2011 vs Ed25519 in 2012/3 and rfc8709 in 2020 (already) implemented by 6.5 in 2014. But it is the _client's_ preference order that determines which hostkey is used, so to force this on the server you must _delete_ the ed25519 key/cert and prevent it being recreated; otherwise on OpenSSH client specify -oHostKeyAlgorithms with ecdsa first or ed25519 removed, and on Putty make similar changes in the Connection/SSH/HostKeys dialog.

Comment: Can't believe I mixed that up - I could have sworn that was the new standard. Maybe they'd gotten it wrong on an article I was using perhaps? In any case, I will try just using the ed25519 standard and see if I can get it working there. Thanks.